# Windows Phone 7 - XAML DateTime literals

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, datetime

How can I get a DateTime property set correctly in XAML under windows phone?

I have tried the following:

```
EndTime="2013-08-26T10:00:00"
EndTime="2013-08-26 10:00"
EndTime="26-08-2013 10:00"
```

Each time I get a `XamlParseException` with message `Failed to create a 'System.DateTime' from the text [whatever input]`

My input should be according to [specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd631811.aspx), but apparently it isn't .

Comment: The link you sent is for WPF. Is your problem in WPF or Windows Phone. Can you show us the XAML code?

Comment: @igrali The problem is in Windows Phone, the code examples are XAML. Try any object with a DateTime property.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a ValueConverter , this link will help you [ValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) .

gd luck .

Answer (score 0):

I try this format: "**8/28/2013 10:34:16**" and it works. hope it's helpful to you.